# Nuxt generate FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to `nuxt generate` my static (with dynamics url params) html pages.
Here's my route config in the `nuxt.config.js` file

```
routes: function () {
      let domain = 'https://example.com'
      if (process.env.NUXT_ENV === 'dev' || process.env.NUXT_ENV === 'development') {
        domain = 'https://dev-example.com'
      }
      if (process.env.NUXT_ENV === 'local') {
        domain = 'http://localhost:3002'
      }
      let rooms = axios.get(domain + '/nuxt/rooms').then((res) => {
        if(res && res.data.length){
          return res.data.map((room) => {
            return '/manage/pro/room/' + room._id
          })
        }else{
          return []
        }
      }).catch(response => {
        console.log('errore room')
      });
      let bookings = axios.get(domain + '/nuxt/users').then((res) => {
        if(res && res.data.length){
          return res.data.map((user) => {
            return '/bookings/' + user.slug
          })
        }else {
          return []
        }
      }).catch(response => {
        console.log('errore rehearsal')
      });
      let user = axios.get(domain + '/nuxt/users').then((res) => {
        if(res && res.data.length){
          return res.data.map((user) => {
            return '/user/' + user._id + '/' + user.username
          })
        }else {
          return []
        }
      }).catch(response => {
        console.log('errore user public')
      });
      let posts = axios.get(domain + '/nuxt/posts').then((res) => {
        if(res && res.data.length){
          return res.data.map((post) => {
            return '/post/' + post._id
          })
        }else {
          return []
        }
      }).catch(response => {
        console.log('errore posts')
      });
      return Promise.all([rooms, posts, user, bookings]).then(values => {
        return values.join().split(',');
      })
    }
  },
```

It' has been always good and the process succeded well till today. Which it seems to require too much RAM memory. Don't know why and don't know how to fix this issue.
Here's the last console output lines

```
2018-09-06T13:12:34.423Z nuxt:render Rendering url /manage/pro/room/5b3f26783e62155502337f8f

<--- Last few GCs --->

[14687:0x2c19ac0]   657918 ms: Mark-sweep 1339.9 (1440.7) -> 1328.1 (1440.2) MB, 2760.7 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.224, current mu = 0.161) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[14687:0x2c19ac0]   661179 ms: Mark-sweep 1341.0 (1440.2) -> 1330.6 (1444.2) MB, 2752.4 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.191, current mu = 0.156) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x5b702a041bd]
    1: StubFrame [pc: 0x5b702a14fb2]
Security context: 0x3e9218f9e589 <JSObject>
    2: rules [0x2590b4e7c449] [/node_modules/clean-css/lib/writer/helpers.js:~46] [pc=0x5b704716ec9](this=0x3e348f706519 <JSGlobal Object>,context=0x1a44edae1691 <Object map = 0x169e1dc614d1>,tokens=0x1806c1ded131 <JSArray[2]>)
    3: all [0x2590b4e7c749] [/node_modules/clean-css/lib...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x89375c [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xe616b2 [node]
 6: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 7: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetry(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
 9: v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [node]
10: v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
11: 0x5b702a041bd
```

Answer (score 16):

Edit your `package.json` and modify your start script to use node with `--max-old-space-size=4096` flag
for example, your package.json may have the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start"
}
```

Use this instead:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js nuxt",
    "build": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js build",
    "start": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js start"
}
```

Some reference: https://medium.com/@vuongtran/how-to-solve-process-out-of-memory-in-node-js-5f0de8f8464c

Comment: "dev": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js nuxt" does not work.

   "dev": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js" does :)
For anyone struggling

Comment: the answer above (almost) works for me with 2k+ products. scripts also needs: "generate": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js generate"

Comment: Getting an error 
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\Code\countersbd\frontend\tms-frontend\node_modules\nuxt\bin\nuxt.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)  
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by an infinite loop. In my case a misconfigured environment variable pointed to the Nuxt server's port at localhost instead of another service.

See more common causes here:

- https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/286
- https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/5931